"mdadm --grow" is stuck with faulty devices
I am not the first one with a stuck mdadm --grow but I think that mine is a bit different from the others. In my case all devices are faulty and the state says FAILED:
root@linux:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md126 
/dev/md126:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jan 26 11:57:52 2021
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 1953258496 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976629248 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Aug 19 14:56:31 2024
             State : active, FAILED, reshaping 
    Active Devices : 0
    Failed Devices : 4
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Reshape Status : 38% complete

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      faulty   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       65        1      faulty   /dev/sde1
       3       8       49        2      faulty   /dev/sdd1
       4       8       33        3      faulty   /dev/sdc1

I created the RAID5 with 3 1TB SSD disks and used it completely for LVM. Yesterday I added a 4th 1TB SSD disk and did the following commands:
mdadm --add /dev/md126 /dev/sdc1
mdadm --grow /dev/md126 --raid-devices=4

At first there was no problem. The RAID5 was still active and slowly accessible. About 4 hours later something must have happened. This morning I checked and the status of mdadm did not change but I lost my RAID5 in LVM although the LVs are still mounted but somehow crippled.
With dmesg I get errors like:
[81591.695415] EXT4-fs (dm-5): I/O error while writing superblock
[81591.710467] EXT4-fs error (device dm-5): __ext4_get_inode_loc_noinmem:4617: inode #524289: block 2097184: comm ls: unable to read itable block
[81591.710488] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-5, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[81591.710495] EXT4-fs (dm-5): I/O error while writing superblock
[82806.711267] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[82806.711279] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[82806.711333] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[82806.711339] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#9 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[82806.711382] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[82806.711388] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#11 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[82806.711431] sd 1:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[82806.711436] sd 1:0:0:0: [sde] tag#21 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00

The mdadm --examine --scan gives no output at all, it just stops. The current content is:
# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md126 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 name=horus:0 UUID=b187df52:41d7a47e:98e7fa00:cae9bf67
   devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1,/dev/sdc1

Looks like the md superblocks are gone:
root@horus:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcde]1
/dev/sda1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :    234441647 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdd1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sde1.

By looking at it now I notice that the devices were not correct. Since 2021 the devices must have changed.
There has always been something strange about my RAID5. It changed from /dev/md0 to /dev/md127 and back once in a while and now, after adding the 4th disk, /dev/md126.
The issue started with:
Aug 19 10:18:20 horus kernel: [ 1787.252546] md: reshape of RAID array md126
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.539238] ahci 0000:01:00.1: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000d address=0xdfd6c000 flags=0x0000]
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835872] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0xe0000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835898] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835914] ata6.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835925] ata6.00: cmd 61/18:88:68:86:ee/00:00:2c:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 12288 out
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835925]          res 40/00:98:80:86:ee/00:00:2c:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835962] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835973] ata6.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835985] ata6.00: cmd 61/18:90:80:8a:ee/00:00:2c:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 12288 out
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.835985]          res 40/00:98:80:86:ee/00:00:2c:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.836022] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.836034] ata6.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.836045] ata6.00: cmd 61/18:98:80:86:ee/00:00:2c:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 12288 out
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.836045]          res 40/00:98:80:86:ee/00:00:2c:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.836082] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 19 14:53:31 horus kernel: [18298.836096] ata6: hard resetting link

Looks like the last entered disk has died during the grow.
Is there a solution for this? Should I stop mdadm and restart the grow? Something else?

You're running --examine on the wrong device, try /dev/sd*1. Get rid of level= num-devices= devices= etc. in your mdadm.conf, just keep the UUID= nothing else. If any log survived it would be good to see how this all started...

The result of --examine /dev/sd*1 is the same. I will dig deeper in the logfiles.

I added the lines from the kern.log Between 10:18:20 and 14:53:31 no messages where logged.

I decided to reboot my server. Since I lost a disk during grow and my LVM configuration I wanted to start as soon as possible with the recreation.
After the reboot my disks came back and also the LVM configuration too. mdadm continued to do the grow and after 4 hours it finished and it looks like I lost no data.
What caused the issue will always remain a question. But rebooting during the grow did not result in a loss of data.

To me, it sort of looks like your AHCI SATA controller may have become stuck in a fault (or somehow glitched) state, and the reboot was just the thing to get it back to its senses.
